Laravel 11 weird undefined array key "name" when sending email
Like the title says, I am trying to send email but it keeps on getting this error.
ContactController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;
use App\Mail\ContactMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the user's profile form.
     */
    public function contact(ContactFormRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        $mailData = $request->validated();
        \Log::info(config('mail.to.address'));
        \Log::info($mailData);
        Mail::to(config('mail.to.address'))->send(new ContactMail($mailData)); // error points to here.
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}

ContactMail.php
class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $mailData = [];

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        \Log::info("did construct");
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }
}

Logs
[2024-04-25 02:38:59] local.INFO: to@example.com  
[2024-04-25 02:38:59] local.INFO: array (
  'contact-name' => 'name',
  'contact-name-furigana' => 'ネイム',
  'contact-email' => 'name@name.com',
  'contact-phone' => '1234',
  'contact-contents' => 'contents',
  'contact-privacy' => 1,
)  

Error
Undefined array key "name" {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key \"name\" at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php:479)

It is not even hitting the ContactMail class.
First I thought the issue was with the import use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; but this is what is used in the tutorial.

I think I got it.
I was trying to add MAIL_TO_ADDRESS="to@example.com" in the .env and also in the app\config\mail.php.
In my mail.php, I only added
    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    ],

I guess laravel is only accepting "to:address" and "to:name" as a pair or none at all. So I change it to
    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

